# c++ can't compile on linux because of a line I have deleted

Tags: c++

I'm trying to compile my code which had a faulty line. I have deleted that line but still the compilation fail because of some ghost:

> /tmp/ccaWghvE.o: In function
>   `show(lipid*)':
>   membrane.cpp:(.text+0xf52): multiple
>   definition of`show(lipid*)'
>   /tmp/ccQicBxx.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x150):
>   first defined here collect2: ld
>   returned 1 exit status

How can I get rid of that?

Thanks

**Solved**

I have used ralu tip and created anew folder and copied everything into it.
Thanks

Comment: We can't do anything without the code. Just deleting a faulty line isn't enough, in fact, the effects could be disastrous.

Comment: What are the command(s) you are using to build the software?

Comment: Try to delete all source

Comment: I use g++ main.cpp particles.cpp properties.cpp membrane.cpp vec.cpp randomizer.cpp -o bin/main. I wouldn't mind pasting my code in but I don't think it will give you any information... @ralu, do you mean deleting all my code?

Comment: Usually: `make clean` will clean all temporary files from the directory.

Answer (score 8):

You defined `show(lipid*)` both in `main.cpp` and in `membrane.cpp`. Either you have copies of the same function in both files *or* you have the function defined non-inline in a header they both include.

Answer (score 1):

It says 'multiple definition'.  You've defined something more than once.  Make sure you only define it once!

Deleting the line the error is on rarely fixes the problem.  That's often just the point the compiler realised something was wrong.  You need to understand the error message, and correct the whole program, not just that line.

Answer (score 1):

You have a doubly defined symbol.

presumably you defined `show(lipid*)` in a header file and included that header file from multiple translation units. To solve this issue, declare it `inline` or move the definition (the actual code) to a `cpp` file, retaining the declaration in the header file.